# Close pop-up from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have two sites (both within my control)

*Site 1 - opens a pop-up on Site 2. To open the popup on site 2 i have the below*

```
Dim strPopup As String = "<script language='javascript' ID='script1'>" + "window.open('" & http://site2.com/customer.aspx" & ",'pop', 'top=90, left=200, width=1000, height=800, dependant=no, location=0, alwaysRaised=no, menubar=no, resizeable=no, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no, status=no, center=yes')" + "</script>"

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page), GetType(Page), "Script1", strPopup, False)
```

**Note**: the `'pop'` within the code above is the name of the form according to my understanding.

So far this works as expected.

*Site 2 displays the pop-up from above and has a button on it. I would like to close the popup/window opened above so tweaked the above script and added it to the button event in code behind on site 2*

```
Dim strPopup As String = "<script language='javascript' ID='script1'>" + "window.close" + "</script>"

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page), GetType(Page), "Script1", strPopup, False)
```

but this doesnt work. Ive tried

`pop.close` (pop is the name given to the form on the first code i posted)

I'm a little lost on how to close the open window within a button event in code behind (please note within the pop-up the user is saving data when they click this button so the idea is to close the button once they click the Save button)

Comment: Did you try replace `window.close` to `window.close()` (with round brakets)?

Comment: Yep that did it!! Feel free to add it as an answer and i will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.close` is a function. You should use `window.close()` (with round brakets) instead of `window.close`.