# Refresh parent page from another URL

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have two sites (both under my control). Site one opens a page on site 2 (See [Close pop-up from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35175664/close-pop-up-from-code-behind) if you wish to see the code)

When i close the pop-up (on site 2) i would like to refresh the parent page (from site 1). I used the JS below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        var retVal = confirm("Are you sure ?");
        if (retVal == true) {
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    </script>


Button: OnClientClick="refreshParent()"
```

But this closes the window and not refresh the page. How could i refresh the parent page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do a return false after calling the reload method otherwise the child would make a request to the server.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for

```
window.parent.location.reload()
```

That being said, there is one issue in your code that may need your attention; the line

```
window.onunload = refreshParent;
```

This is assigning `refreshParent` before it is defined. When this line is executed it will likely throw an exception and cause the rest of your javascript code (below it) to be skipped. To fix this, just move that line to a position below the function definition.

With all the above changes in place, your javascript code may end up looking something like this

```
function refreshParent() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
        window.parent.location.reload();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    } 
}
window.onunload = refreshParent;
```